# How to programmatically create new objects from rows of data in Python / Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

[image]I have a worksheet in google sheets where each row is information about an upcoming event, including the name, location, tickets etc...

I have a class Event and I'd like to create a new instance of Event for every row in the worksheet, but I want the name of the new Event objects to be values from the row.

Creating the class is easy enough because I can set attributes like

```
self.venue = worksheet.cell(foo,bar).value
```

But I'm not sure how to use the same logic for the name of the variable when creating the object

e.g.

```
worksheet.cell(row, column).value = Event(etc...)
```

I need some way to say create this new Event and name the variable worksheet.cell(row, column).value for row in this worksheet

Edit: added example of the data I'm working with. The 'band' column is the one with the strings that I would like to use as names for newly created objects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to do it. But the most recommended way to do so is using dictionaries and not just naming the objects dynamically. For example:

```
EventObjects = {}

# and for each row and col that you want to create the objec
EventObjects[worksheet.cell(row, column).value] = Event(etc..)
```

Then when you want to access it, you can just get the instance of the object as so:

```
EventObjects['<Name>'].time
```

The other (not recommended way) is to use setattr:

```
import sys

# Assuming that this code is just executed in main.
# If not, just substitute sys.modules['__main__'] with the instance in which
# you want to create the varible
# like for example:
# settar(self, 'a', 10) creates a variable self.a with value 10

# For every row and column
setattr(sys.modules['__main__'], worksheet.cell(row, column).value, Event(etc ..))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the class attributes by editing its `__dict__`:

```
Event.__dict__[worksheet.cell(row, column).value] = ...
```

(assuming `worksheet.cell(row, column).value` is a string).